# Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target - angularfire2

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic3, angularfire2

Please how do i resolve this issue when using ionic 3 and angularfire2

'Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target' when i 
call

```
 this.profileObject=this.db.object(`/profiles/${user.uid}`,{preserveSnapshot: true});
```

It states only 1 parameter allowed but i have looked at examples and documentations they all allowed the option parameter {preserveSnapshot: true }.
This is my code below

```
profileObject: FirebaseObjectObservable<Profile>;
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    console.log('Hello DataProvider Provider');
  }
  getProfile(user: User){
    this.profileObject=this.db.object(`/profiles/${user.uid}`,{preserveSnapshot: true});
  return this.profileObject.take(1);
  }
```

Thanks and please all suggestion and answer are welcomed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using latest [**Angularfire2 5.0.0-rc.3**](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/releases/tag/5.0.0-rc.3) then this is not an issue.

Here is the confirmation from [**Angularfire2 Author**](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1061#issuecomment-333619747).

> Not a problem in the newest version - David